# Use subquery after AS alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery, alias

I am trying to use subquery after alias AS in SQL server 2019, here is my sql query:

```
select concat(sum(labst),' kg') as (select distinct name1 from mb52 where werks='1202') from mb52 where werks='1202';
```

but this query giving this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near '('.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

I want to get the result like this:

```
1202
--------------------------------------------
343979.535 kg
```

instead of using `select concat(sum(labst),' kg') as "1202"`,
because I get the value of werks from a variable $werks and my final SQL query look like this:

```
select concat(sum(labst),' kg') as (select distinct name1 from mb52 where werks in ($werks)) from mb52 where werks in ($werks);
```

Can anyone help me on this problem,please?

Comment: I think that dynamic sql is the only way to do this

Comment: @GuidoG, could you please provide some examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql like this

```
declare @sql varchar(1000)
declare @name varchar(100)
declare @werks varchar(1000) = '1202, 1200'

select distinct
       @name = name1 
from   mb52
where  werks = 1202


set @sql = 'select concat(sum(labst), '' kg'') as ''' + @name + ''' from mb52 where werks in (' + @werks + ')'

exec (@sql)
```

See this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9421fa533b890219b3ee75dec67906bc) where you can try it yourself

However, there is a major problem with your query, as you write

```
as (select distinct name1 from mb52 where werks in ($werks))
```

This can return more than one value for `name1` if there are more then one value in $werks

So I changed it to `= 1202` like the other answer also did
Your query probably needs to more like this

```
set @sql2 = 'select concat(sum(labst), '' kg'') as ''' + @name + ''' from mb52 where werks = 1202'
```

where again I changed the `in $werks` into `= 1202` because I think it will produce wrong results, but that is up to you.
Look at the dbfiddle and play with it until it does what you need.

**EDIT**

As requested in the comments, here is how the query looks like with just one value in $werks

```
set @sql2 = 'select concat(sum(labst), '' kg'') as ''' + @name + ''' from mb52 where werks = ' + @werks
```

The [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9421fa533b890219b3ee75dec67906bc) is also altered

Comment: let say $werks has only one value, how can we put this $werks in your query, but not 1202?

Comment: I put an EDIT in my answer that shows that

Answer (score 0):

you should use dynamic sql to get this working

```
DECLARE @S NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT distinct @S = 'select concat(sum(labst),'' kg'') as '+ name1 +' from mb52 where werks=''1202''' from mb52 where werks='1202'
EXEC (@S)
```

Comment: your query gave this error:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'kg'

I think there is a problem with quotes

Comment: @Jonibek yes there was. Fixed now.

Comment: @Jonibek as you can see there is no fact word 'fact' in the query that was shared? Are you looking at something else?

Comment: oooh, I am so sorry, this error:
Incorrect syntax near '1202'

Comment: DhruvJoshi thanks, when I put double quotes, it worked,  '''+ name1 +'''

Comment: can we put $werks instead of 1202? cause variable $werks equals to 1202

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to use a dynamic query
like this:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'select concat(sum(t1.labst),'' kg'') as '+  (SELECT DISTINCT
t1.name1  FROM dbo.mb52 t1  WHERE t1.werks = '1202') + ' from dbo.mb52 t1 where    t1.werks=''1202'''
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: I got an error: Incorrect syntax near '1202'

Comment: can we put $werks instead of 1202?
cause $werks equals to 1202